# When I add settings folder with settings for different environments, I get CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False

Tags: python, django

I want to make two files with different settings for dev and prod.

I created a python package in the app folder where my settings are, and even if I run the app with old settings, I receive an error:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Comment: can you show the `manage.py` file as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I should specify the path to my settings in my run settings:
[image]

Also, in I should change my BASE_DIR by adding one more parent here:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Well at first for this purpose:

> I want to make two files with different settings for dev and prod.

You should move to `settings.py` module to `settings` *dir* at first and it's better to change its name to for example `base.py`. After that, you can provide two modules called `dev.py` and `prod.py` for a different modes of your projects.

Also with these changes, you must change the route of your settings in `manage.py` module.

Note: with these changes, you can provide different values for `DEBUG`, `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, etc. in your different modes.